# How to ascending order the following integers with maple (should not display any digit)

Tags: integer, display, digits, maple

In this exercise you should not display any digit. Display
only the minimal output required to establish your result.
(a) Place the following integers in ascending order
100^(100); 80^(120); 60^(140); 40^(160)

`evalb(-3<-2)`

anyone can help what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear whether you have to show it by steps, or whether you can simply get Maple to sort the quantities directly.

Consider these three comparisons, which should be enough for you to figure out the ascending order:

```
evalb( 80^(120) > 100^(100) );

           true

evalb( 60^140 > 80^(120) );

           true

evalb( 40^(160) > 60^140 );

           true
```

Or, starting with a random rearrangement, you can get Maple to sort them.

```
restart;

# separate paragraph or execution group
interface(typesetting=extended):

S := [100%^(100), 40%^(160), 60%^(140), 80%^(120) ];

answer := sort(S, (a,b)->value(a)<value(b));
```

Comment: thankyou so much, but i prefer this
```S := [100^(100), 40^(160), 60^(140), 80^(120) ];
answer := sort(S); ```

but how to show online the "100^100, .." without showing the accumulation?

Comment: Yes,, that is the whole point of my using the inert `%^` (and `value` in the comparison function, inside `sort`), so that the actual digits are not shown.